# What is meant by a compression codec's splittability in the context of Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, compression, hdfs

I was learning about various compression codecs when I came across a term 'splittable'. Now this term has not been explained much in any of the internet sources and books I have looked into, so I guess I might be missing something trivial here. My first guess is that certain codecs add metadata as headers/trailers into the compressed files, and this would mean that if the a compressed file is split into multiple HDFS blocks for storage, it wouldn't be of any use unless all its splits are consolidated together. If this is the case, how are the splits(blocks) of a non-splittable file sent to mappers for input to a MR application?

I know for a fact that hadoop does support gzip(non splittable codec) but I do not understand exactly how.

Can someone give an elaborate explanation to what are the implications of non-splittability of a codec or share some links that do the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excerpt from "Hadoop The Definitive Guide" by Tom White, the chapter on Hadoop I/O, Compression and Input Splits:

> Lets assume we have a file of 1 GB size in HDFS whose block size is 64 MB. Which implies the file is stored in 16 blocks. The MapReduce job using this file as input will create 16 input splits, each processed independently as input to a separate map task.
>
> Imagine now the file is a gzip-compressed file whose compressed size is 1 GB. As before, HDFS will store the file as 16 blocks. However, creating a split for each block won’t work since it is impossible to start reading at an arbitrary point in the gzip stream and therefore impossible for a map task to read its split independently of the others. The gzip format uses DEFLATE to store the compressed data, and DEFLATE stores data as a series of compressed blocks. The problem is that the start of each block is not distinguished in any way that would allow a reader positioned at an arbitrary point in the stream to advance to the beginning of the next block, thereby synchronizing itself with the stream. For this reason, gzip does not support splitting.
>
> In this case, MapReduce will do the right thing and not try to split the gzipped file, since it knows that the input is gzip-compressed (by looking at the filename extension) and that gzip does not support splitting. This will work, but at the expense of locality: a single map will process the 16 HDFS blocks, most of which will not be local to the map. Also, with fewer maps, the job is less granular, and so may take longer to run.
>
> If the file in our hypothetical example were an LZO file, we would have the same problem since the underlying compression format does not provide a way for a reader to synchronize itself with the stream. However, it is possible to preprocess LZO files using an indexer tool that comes with the Hadoop LZO libraries. The tool builds an index of split points, effectively making them splittable when the appropriate MapReduce input format is used.

A bzip2 file, on the other hand, does provide a synchronization marker between blocks (a 48-bit approximation of pi), so it does support splitting.

```
Compression format| Algorithm | Splittable
-------------------------------------------------------------------
gzip              | DEFLATE   | No
bzip2             | bzip2     | Yes
LZO               | LZO       | Yes 
Snappy            | Snappy    | No
```

Refer [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/hadoop-compression-choosing-compression-codec-part2) for more details on compression and splits

Comment: Great Explanation!! Thank You. Just one question.. Is the compression codec really identified using the filename extension? What if I remove the extension of a gzip file and feed it to my application (It would probably fail miserably but I am interested in understanding the lower level details of the same)

Comment: Seems like almost all of this is a direct quote from a book. Please take a look at: [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). In addition to taking credit for the work of others, it's robbing readers of a chance to get more details.

Comment: Thanks @JonEricson for adding the book reference,missed it.